# What is the alternative for the ignitevisor.sh 'cache' command in new version 2.15.0

Tags: ignite

In version 2.14.0 there is ignitevisor.sh tool with `cache` parameter allows to see table of caches and number of elementes in each cache. Ignitevisor now deprecated.

New 2.15.0 control.sh tool doesn't show such table.
How can view caches an number of elements inside caches?

===

Update: control.sh worked for me, not as ignitevisor though.
I'm using Apache Ignite docker and control.sh has output:

Thank you for the answer.
Now I'm using official docker image and when control.sh script is launched the output has:

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2 (file:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-2.15.0-bin/libs/ignite-core-2.15.0.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
...

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, the control.sh script is the replacement. For example, to get a list of caches:

```
control.sh --cache list .
```

And then, to get the size, you can extract metrics:

```
control.sh --metric cache.SQL_PUBLIC_PERSON.CacheSize
```

This gets the size of the SQL_PUBLIC_PERSON cache.